# Can a mine in minesweeper touch only a single number tile

Tags: minesweeper

So i was playing some games and almost every game, i found a luck based situation, but are they actually luck based positions?

I have gone with this strategy, where when i am question marking tiles, i try to not check the spots that touch only a single number tile, only the ones that touch more than 1 number tile.

Is this right? Do mines appear touching at least 2 number tiles?

(not talking about custom boards, where it is possible to get mines that touch no number tile.)

Comment: Wait... are you asking about the boardset of a specific minesweeper implementation/version?

Answer (score 1):

> It is easy for a mine to tough only one number tile... if it is adjacent to other mines.  Three mines in the corner produces a mine that touches one number tile in a pretty straightforward way.